# Findiing a value if that falls within the range

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and writing a python code to check if a given value falls within a range.

From traffic generator, i get the tx and rx packets. for the rx packets i add or negate the threshold value and proceed with my test case.

As an example, if tx = 2000 and rx is 2000, threshold is 10, then i want to proceed with my testing only when rx is 1990 to 2010.

I have written the code as below:

```
lower_range_exp_packet = tx_stat - threshold
higher_range_exp_packet =  tx_stat + threshold
if rx_stat in range(int(lower_range_exp_packet),int(higher_range_exp_packet)):
    log.info('The traffic test is pass as expected ...')
```

but just thinking if there is an easiest or more pythonic way to do it insteading of computing the boundries.. 
pls advise.

Comment: `(tx - 10) <= rx <= (tx+10)`, which works internally as `((tx - 10) <= rx) and ((tx + 10) >= rx)`

Comment: You can also use `if abs(rx_stat - tx_stat) <= threshold:`.

Comment: Thanks selcuk, The absolute one worked like a charm.. Thanks again

Comment: Please not that `if rx_stat in range(a, b)` really means `if a <= rx_stat < b`. So `rx_stat` can never be `b`.  The quicker test `if abs(tx_stat - rx_stat) <= threshold`, replaces 3 lines with only 1. Which probably is more readable and more easily to adapt to changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
lower_range_exp_packet = tx_stat - threshold
higher_range_exp_packet =  tx_stat + threshold
if lower_range_exp_packet <= rx_stat <= higher_range_exp_packet:
    log.info('The traffic test is pass as expected ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help to meet your criteria:

```
lower_range_exp_packet = tx_stat - threshold
higher_range_exp_packet =  tx_stat + threshold
if rx_stat >= lower_range_exp_packet and rx_stat <= higher_range_exp_packet:
    log.info('The traffic test is pass as expected ...')
```